# Android App: How can I request extra time on shutdown to finish saving files?

Tags: android, file, persistence

I'm running into an issue that I believe is caused by Android terminating my app while my app is still writing data to a file.

On iOS, I can do this to force the OS to wait until I finish everything before shutting down:

```
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier aTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:aTaskID];
    }
```

Is there some equivalent for me to call on Android so that the OS knows that I'm doing cleanup work and I just need to finish writing these files before it exterminates the app itself?

Comment: Atish's answer is good, also you can start a `Service`, which is really little more than a formal request to the OS, "I'd like to do something in the background". Android will usually give a background Service a few minutes before it preemptively kills it (Oreo+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Activity LifeCycle Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), the methods onPause() and onStop() will always be called when the app is getting destroyed. However, doing any CPU intensive tasks should always be carried out in the onStop() method of the Activity.

As per your requirement, I would suggest you do your CleanUp work in the onStop() method of the Activity.

If you think that Android OS is killing your app, it means, the OS is trying to free memory resources for other apps to take place, hence, the onStop() method will be invoked and you can implement your logic to save the data in this method.

I would not recommend using the onPause() method, as it can get called too frequently for scenarios like quick switching between other apps, incoming phone call etc.